# set env variable from a Makefile command and use in another Make command

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to connect to some API using python script. that API requires an env variable to be available. to get that env I have another command. I combined both commands in one single Makefile command

```
# Current Makefile
cmd_1:
    $(eval MY_ENV := $somevalue)
    MY_ENV=$(MY_ENV) python myscript.py cmd_1

cmd_2:
    $(eval MY_ENV := $somevalue)
    MY_ENV=$(MY_ENV) python myscript.py cmd_2
```

Now as you can see some part(1st line) is same in both above commands. I want to get rid of that duplicacy. I want something like the below so that I can reuse it even if in future I have more than 2 mgmt commands.

```
# Desired Makefile (Using DRY)?
get_env:
        $(eval MY_ENV := $somevalue)
    
cmd_1:
        MY_ENV=$(MY_ENV) python myscript.py cmd_1

cmd_2:
        MY_ENV=$(MY_ENV) python myscript.py cmd_2
```

I tried to wrap these two commands and create another Make command, like below. but no luck.

```
mycmd:
    @$(MAKE) get_env
    @$(MAKE) cmd_1
```

So I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Changing your question after receiving an answer is just confusing for future visitors. Now the answer doesn't make sense because it refers to an earlier version of the question. (There's a pending edit to the answer so I won't roll back now; but going forward, please don't do that.)

Comment: I agree with tripleee: I had to change both the question and the answer to make it an answer to the question again! Please don't change it again.

Comment: Why are you trying to set the variable in an `eval` inside a recipe?  If you want it to be in effect for both rules why not just set it as a make variable at a global level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suggest this:

```
get_env ::
    $(eval MY_ENV := $somevalue)

cmd_1 cmd_2 :: get_env
    MY_ENV=$(MY_ENV) python myscript.py $@
```

Some explanations:

- `::` makes the targets phony, so you won't have to add a line `.PHONY: get_env cmd_1 cmd_2` in the Makefile;
- `$@` is the current target

The key point is to add a dependency to `get_env` in the rule, so that `MY_ENV` is kept.

For a simpler trial, run `make bar` or `make baz` with this toy Makefile:

```
foo ::
    $(eval qux := `pwd`)

bar baz :: foo
    @echo "qux = $(qux) and target = $@"
```